# Cannot move subscription from child to parent management group

Tags: azure-rbac, azure-management-groups

I am working on the AZ104 exercise Lab2 [(link here)](http://and%20I%20am%20literally%20at%20the%20FINAL%20STEP%20of%20the%20exercise%20(Clean%20Up%20Resources%20Step%2011)%20but%20I%20could%20not%20delete%20the%20%27az104-02-mg1%27%20management%20group%20-%20screenshot%20below%20shows%20the%20%27hierarchy%27%20of%20the%20management%20groups%20-%20the%20%27az104-02-mg1%27%20is%20currently%20UNDER%20the%20Tenant%20Root%20Group.) and  I am at the Clean Up Resources Step 9 where it says to move the subscription under the 'az104-02-mg1' management group to its parent, the 'Tenant Root Group'.

Here is what - if I am right? - is the current hierarchy of the management groups - with the parent mgmt group being “Tenant Root Group and the child 'az104-02-mg1' management group - which, as you can see  is the one associated with the 'Azure subscription 1' subscription.  Then I clicked on the ellipsis (i.e, the three dots) to the right of the 'Azure subscription 1' which shows the 'Move' option (see screenshot below).

[image]

Clicking on the "move" text reveals a new sidebar panel showing the "new parent management group defaulted to our Tenant Root Group which is exactly where we want to move our subscription to.

[image]

I clicked on the Save button to process the request, expecting a successful operation.  Instead I got this error.

[image]

I am stumped.  I logged on with my main account to do this operation.  But just in case, I want to show you guys the Subscription Access Control (IAM) page's 'Role Assignments'.  screenshot. It originally only showed 'User Access Administrator' Role and I could not move the subscription, so I added the 'Owner' to the Subscription IAM role for my main account.  Yet it is still not working.

[image]

What could I be missing?  Help from the Azure community is greatly appreciated!

Update:  I just noticed this belatedly.  Why is the following picture showing “Parent management group” as az104-02-mg1?  If you look back at the very first screenshot from the top, I assume that first screenshot above shows the manamegement group hierarchy with the “Tenant Root Group” being the parent and the ‘az104-02-mg1’ is the child management group, am I right?  Or am I reading that first screenshot wrong?

[image]

Update 2: if I read the first screenshot correctly as the management group hierarchy, here is my next question.  I saw the following Azure doc related to my issue - the text in the red box says if the “existing parent management group is the root management group then PERMISSIONS ARE NOT NECESSARY“ - shouldn’t this apply to my situation above?

[image]

Comment: This is more of technical issue. Please reach out to Azure Technical Support teams via https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/. They will help with troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: unfortunately I am using the free Azure trial in doing the AZ104 lab - the support requires a paid account.

Comment: Even if you dont have Technical Support, you'll be allowed to chat with Technical Engineer  who support Azure free trail Customers.

Comment: Do you have the link to it?  I have not been able to find it.  Appreciate your input!

Comment: I shared you the link above. Once you fill all the details, at last you'll get a option to chat. that will connect directly with Support engineer.

Comment: were you able to get help from Support teams ?

Comment: yes, theyre looking into it as we speak.  Expecting their call sometime today.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the Azure subscription 1 that's associated to az104-02-mg1 to the Tenant Root Group first (ellipses > move) then you can delete the subscription.  Once that is deleted you can then delete the management group az104-02-mg1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).